# How to overcome error in (HttpWebResponse)HttpReq.GetResponse()?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I am getting a Error in GetResponse() method while using it in visual studio 2012 for mobile,but it works fine in visual studio desktop version,Please Help,

> The Code is as shown

```
  var myurl = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/4b1ac2aa66db99adcf90578132b507d4/";


        string url = myurl + lat + "," + lon; 

        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse () as HttpWebResponse) {            
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                //Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
            }
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ())) {
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd ();
                Console.WriteLine (reader.ReadToEnd ());
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (content)) {
                    //Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                } else {   
                    myopt = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (content);


                    System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime (1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    double unixTimeStamp = 1392316200;
                    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds (myopt.hourly.data [23].time).ToLocalTime ();
```

myopt is object of rootobject class for various Json classes.
Please Help me as I am pretty new to this field,Thanks

Comment: Use BeginGetResponse() instead of GetResponse () method.

Comment: Can you specify what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone all Http requests are done asynchrounously. So you can't call `GetReponse()` because it is blocking. Instead, you should use the asynchronous call `BeginGetResponse` and pass it a callback function that'll be called when the response is received.

Here's how you'd do a simple HttpWebRequest asynchronously:

```
string myUrl = "http://example.com"

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(myUrl);
request.BeginGetResponse(myCallback, request);
```

And then define the callback like this:

```
void myCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request != null)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
            //You can check the response code this way
            if (reponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                //Do stuff with your response
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            //Handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Since this is an asynchronous call, the callback method is called in a new thread which is different from the one in which you created the request. So make sure you take this into account to avoid invalid cross-thread access.

Refer [to here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221581.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks,Can you tell me how to check status code using the webresponse object??

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to check the status code. The status code is only defined in Http so you need to use `HttpWebResponse` instead of `WebReponse`.